# Iniciante em Javascipt

Tags: javascript

Galera preciso de uma help, estou fazendo uns exercícios e travei em 3 específicos sobre string, é simples mas já tentei de tudo e não consigo achar os erros.

Ex 1: Criar uma função **perímetro** que nos diga o perímetro de um círculo quando damos a ele o raio como parâmetro. Também a função **área** que nos dá a área de um círculo quando recebe o raio como parâmetro.

```js
    function  perimetro(raio) {
    var perimetro = π * raio * 2;
    return perimetro;
}
    function area(raio) {
    var area = π * raio * raio;
    return area;
} 
\\Retorna dizendo que as variáveis locais são desnecessárias e que poderia retornar a expressão diretamente.
```

Ex 2: Criar uma função chamada **tamanhoNomeCompleto**, que recebe um nome e um sobrenome como parâmetros, e que irá devolver o tamanho total, contando um espaço extra para separar ambos.

```js
    function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome, sobrenome) {
    var NomeCompleto = (nome.lenght + sobrenome.length);
    var tamanhoNomeCompleto = 6;
    return tamanhoNomeCompleto; 
 }
```

Ex 3: Criar uma função **escreverCartao**, que recebe como parâmetros um título, um nome e um sobrenome e retorna uma única string como resultado.

```js
    function escreverCartao() {
    var titulo = "Dra";
    var nome = "Ana";
    var sobrenome = "Pérez";
    var escreverCartao = (titulo + " " + nome + " " + sobrenome);
    return titulo + " " + nome + " " + sobrenome
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No EX2:**
Seguindo a sugestão do @Rick, mas, considerando que para aprendizado é sempre bom uma melhor clareza e de quebra menos chamadas a função length, sugiro o seguinte código:

```
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome, sobrenome) {
    return (nome + " " + sobrenome).length;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No Ex 1, não é um erro mas apenas um aviso, pois vc está criando uma variável parar retornar um valor que poderia ser retornado diretamente, ex.:

```
function  perimetro(raio) {
   return π * raio * 2;
}
```

No Ex 2, vc está definindo uma variável com valor 6 e retornado, ou seja, qualquer valor que passar por parâmetro o retorno sempre será 6.

```
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome, sobrenome) {
    return nome.length + sobrenome.length + 1; // + 1 seria para contar o espaço
}
```

No Ex 3, vc não está passando as variáveis por paramento, mas criando localmente com um valor estático.

```
function escreverCartao(titulo, nome, sobrenome) {
    return titulo + " " + nome + " " + sobrenome
}
```

Comment: E quanto à variável `π` no primeiro?

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda com os exercícios, no 1 e 3 funcionou corretamente sua solução porém no 2 ainda apresenta erro "Nan == 10" \\Usei um número aleatório

Comment: Acredito que vc possa estar utilizando `nome.lenght` ao invés de `nome.length`, assim como utilizou no exemplo da pergunta

Answer (score 1):

No Ex 3. Funcionou pra mim desta forma:

```
function escreverCartao(titulo=“Dra.”, nome=“Ana”, sobrenome=“Pérez”) {
    return titulo + “ “ + nome + “ “ + sobrenome;
}
```

Substitua as informações pelo conteúdo que vc quiser!! :)

Answer (score 0):

No primeiro exemplo faça assim:

```
function  perimetro(raio) {
   return 3.14 * raio * 2;
}
    function area(raio) {
    return 3.14 * raio * raio;
}
```

Pra mim deu certo.

Answer (score -1):

No Exemplo contar nome e sobre nome funcionou assim

```
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(Juan, Perez) {
    return Juan.length + Perez.length + 1; // + 1 seria para contar o espaço
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Segue resposta do EX 2:

```
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome, sobrenome) {
    return nome.length + " ".length + sobrenome.length
}
```